# Cannot boot from Ubuntu 16.04 (desktop version) USB startup drive on Lenovo T460p with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, usb, lenovo

I created a USB startup drive and tested that the drive works on my old computer lenovo t430s. I was able to boot from USB without any problem. On my new computer t460p, I was able to see the USB drive device from the boot menu and if I select to boot from it. It does not do anything. It does not seem to detect anything on the USB.

I tried two different USB as well. It does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue also on a T460p.
1st fix: 
I followed the instructions on
https://support.lenovo.com/ch/en/documents/ht103058.
I set boot mode to "Both" and that helped (step 3 of the instructions for Think-branded systems).

2nd fix: 
I copied the efi image to usb via

```
# dd if=ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso  of=/dev/sdX
```

then pressed F12 during boot and opted to boot from my USB drive. I was actually able to boot in UEFI mode. The latter proved crucial for my ubuntu 16.04.1 installation.

--
that's me in the corner,
that's me in the spot light,
shooting my computer ...

Comment: I end up using USB DVD boot.

Comment: Alrite. All the best of luck installing linux on an UEFI system.